# Browser showing 200 status code and showing as cached

Tags: caching, nginx

We are using nginx for serving static files. Below is the config:

```
# To serve files with version appended as ?v=0.2 etc. 
# for app level js and css only
location ~ ^/(assets/js/|assets/css/) {
  root /path/to/static/files/public;
  access_log off;
  expires max;
  try_files $uri $1;
}

# other static files
location ~ ^/(assets/|images/|favicon.ico) {
  root /path/to/static/files/public;
  access_log off;
  expires max;
}
```

Now what i am seeing in the browser is sometimes it gives 200 for even cached files. and sometimes gives 304. [image]

I enabled the nginx access logs and confirmed that even if the status code is 200, if its cached, its not hitting the nginx server.
But then why its giving 200 status code instead of 304 for cached files? Is anything wrong with my config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.

By using `expires [some-date-in-the-future]` you're basically telling the Browser to use it's local cache to serve the request until that date is reached. 
The Browsers local cache *answers* with a `200 OK` response, since that's what the Protocol expects if a resource is successfully fetched.

Beyond that date the browser is clever enough to ask the server, if a Resource changed since last access by using the `If-Modified-Since` header. If the Server answers `304 Not Modified` the Browser happily re-uses the version from its local cache again.